# What does setValue(value:forKey:) do in Firebase Auth?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I was playing around with Firebase Auth and I noticed all `FirebaseAuth.User` instances have a method called `setValue(value:forKey:)`. I searched around in the "Manage Users" section of the Firebase Auth Docs but found no reference of it.

I wanted to know what it does. I'm guessing you can use it to set some special value (somewhat like a property) to a `FirebaseAuth.User`. If that's the case would it be useful for storing additional data associated with a user such as "preferredGenres" or "emergencyNumber"?

Please let me know what `setValue(value:forKey:)` does, what are its uses, and if my assumption is correct.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from `User` class declaration:
`class User : NSObject, UserInfo` it inherited from an `NSObject` which has `setValue(value:forKey:)` method. Within `NSObject` this method allows to set any properties via `String` key. Apple docs are here: [setValue(forKey:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1415969-setvalue)

So in common you can just access and mutate all the existing User properties but in a less safe manner.